# docx to list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-docx

I am trying to read a docx file and to add the text to a list.
Now I need the list to contain lines from the docx file.

example:

docx file:

```
"Hello, my name is blabla,
I am 30 years old.
I have two kids."
```

result:

```
['Hello, my name is blabla', 'I am 30 years old', 'I have two kids']
```

I cant get it to work.

Using the `docx2txt` module from here:
[github link](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt)

There is only one command of process and it returns all the text from docx file.

Also I would like it to keep the special characters like `":\-\.\,"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**docx2txt** module reads docx file and converts it in text format.

You need to split above output using `splitlines()` and store it in list.

**Code (Comments inline) :**

```
import docx2txt

text = docx2txt.process("a.docx")

#Prints output after converting
print ("After converting text is ",text)

content = []
for line in text.splitlines():
  #This will ignore empty/blank lines. 
  if line != '':
    #Append to list
    content.append(line)

print (content)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
After converting text is
 Hello, my name is blabla.

I am 30 years old.

I have two kids.

 List is  ['Hello, my name is blabla.', 'I am 30 years old. ', 'I have two kids.']

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: Wow, i spent so much time trying to figure it out. didnt know there is splitlines() command.. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Kiper - Thanks to you also since due to this question I came to know know about docx2txt module.

Comment: Im trying to parse pdfs now, after recieving the text of pdf i am using same method of splitline(). for some reason i get whitespace in the end of each line. what would be the best way to get rid of it? my list looks like that ['word1 ', 'word2 ','word3 '] instead of [word1,word2,word3]

Comment: Use line=line.strip() to get rid of white space

Comment: I swear i tried it. but it worked only after you said it. Thanks again.